# How to make a model tween when a button is clicked

Tags: animation, lua, roblox, tween

My model hierarchy looks like this:

```
1. Core
2. Union
2. (Other parts I want to tween with the door)
2. Button
3. (Inside the button) Click detector
3. (Inside the button) Local script
```

OR

An image so it's easier to read
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDqJ9.png)

```
local button = script.Parent
local parentPart = button.Parent -- Assuming the parent part contains all the parts you want to move together

local startPosition = parentPart.Position -- Set the starting position of the parent part
local endPosition = Vector3.new(0, 5, 0)  -- Replace with the desired end position

local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local function onButtonClicked()
    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
        2,             -- Duration of the tween in seconds
        Enum.EasingStyle.Quad, -- Easing style (you can change this to other styles)
        Enum.EasingDirection.Out
    )
    local tween = TweenService:Create(parentPart, tweenInfo, {Position = endPosition})
    tween:Play()
end

button.MouseClick:Connect(onButtonClicked)
```

I used the previous code and clicked the button. I expected the model to move upwards, to the point I specified.

I clicked it but nothing occured

Answer (score 0):

Does your button part contain a click detector?

```
local clickDetector = script.Parent.ClickDetector
local parentPart = script.Parent

local tweenService = game:GetService('TweenService')

clickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid') then
        local tween = tweenService:Create(parentPart, TweenInfo.new(), {Position = Vector3.new(0,5,0)})
        tween:Play()
    end
end)
```

Comment: yes, it does have a click detector